# enable https on EC2 using nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance where I have a couple docker containers running each one with a specific port, I have also bought a domain name and linked it to the EC2 successfully and now I can access each container by http://my-domaine.com:5000 or http://my-domaine.com:8188.

I wanted to enable HTTPS so I did the following steps:

- enabled https in the security group's inbound rule
- installed nginx on the EC2 instance
- created a free certificate using Let's Encrypt
- created the following configuration under **/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-domaine.com**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-domaine.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name my-domaine.com;

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domaine.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domaine.com/privkey.pem;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8188; // redirect to one of the containers
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

- created a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-domaine.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

- and restarted nginx

but when I go to the browser and access the domaine name via https I get "**This site can’t be reached**" error.

I ran this command to check if the config file is valid or not

```
sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-domaine.com
```

I get this error:

```
"server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-domaine.com:1
```

one thing I noticed when I run **sudo nginx -t** without providing the full path of the custom configuration I get this result :

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

so I ended up with 2 issues:

- the custom configuration file I have created is not valid atfer running **sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-domaine.com**
- nginx didn't take into consideration this new config file

How to fix this?